# passing function to router-outlet components

Tags: angular

I have two functions that I have defined in a service, and I call that service in my nav component. However I still get this error `EXCEPTION: Error in app/html/nav.html:5:48 caused by: Cannot read property 'hoverIn' of undefinedErrorHandler.handleError`

**showhide.service**

```
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
  export class ShowHideService {

   public hoverIn(){
       document.getElementById('title').style.display = 'block';
   };
   public hoverOut(){
       document.getElementById('title').style.display = 'none';
   };

}
```

**nav.component**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ShowHideService } from '../services/showhide.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'nav',
   templateUrl:'./app/html/nav.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app/Css/nav.css'],
})
export class NavComponent {
   constructor(private _showhide: ShowHideService) {

       this._showhide.hoverIn();
       this._showhide.hoverOut();
   }
}
```

**nav.html**

```
 <div class="header">
        <p #title class="title">Title</p>
        <div>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="navItem">
                    <a class="navlinks"  routerLink="/gtm (mouseover)="_showhide.hoverIn()" 
                    (mouseout)="_showhide.hoverOut()">Nav Item</a></li>
                <li class="navItem"><a class="navlinks" routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

thanks in advance If there are any questions or request for more info, I will edit as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

That's a perfect use-case for a shared service.

You can inject this service to every Component you want and use the service functions.

See this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8QTmKJazNSC03saBVy2q?p=catalogue

```js
import {Component, NgModule, Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  public anyFunction() { console.log('!') }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 (mouseover)="_service.anyFunction()" (mouseout)="_service.anyFunction()" >Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor(private _service: MyService) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'

    // now you can use the service in this component..
    this._service.anyFunction();
  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  providers: [ MyService ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, +1 for the help,  but I am now getting a new error with this method,when I (mouseover), while following your example, any advice?

Comment: there is a missing " after routerLink="/gtm <<

Comment: that was just a typeO when transfering my code over, the error mentioned in the first paragraph is still occuring

Comment: I believe so, intellisense finished the function for me so I am assuming it is working. but when I reference it in my html it says its not a function.

Comment: Updated my plunker.. works with mouse-events.. theres something wrong in your project.. create a plunker or check everything again.. maybe a cache problem? try some console.logs.. print the service in your constructor.. give some more input.